# nsRouterLink is not working in nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I need to navigate from one page to another in nativescript(android). I tried in my tns.html

```
<Button [nsRouterLink]="['/grocery', 'list']" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded-lg"
text="Back"></Button>
```

routes.ts

```
export const RootRoutes: Array<any> = [
{
path: '',
component: RootComponent
},
{
path: 'grocery/:type',
component: GroceryComponent
}
];
```

But its not working. No chage will not happend. am new learner of nativescript. what should i do?Any help will really helpful.

Comment: Do you have a route `/grocery` or `/grocery/list`?

Comment: yes i have. am including my routes.ts

Comment: The question was: which one do you have?

Comment: i have grcocery

Comment: Just to check if routing works ok you could change `routes.ts` to `path: 'grocery'` and the html to `[nsRouterLink]="['/grocery']"`.

Comment: actually i need to pass parameter along with this grocery like grocery/view. in my forward button nsRouterLink is works perfectly, but if it is back button it will not works. <Button [nsRouterLink]="['/grocery', 'room']" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded-lg" text="Tap for Room Change"></Button> it works perfectly.

Comment: How about using `router.back()` in your component?

Comment: you mean like this <Button text="Back" (tap)="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded-lg"></Button> and in  component.ts                 goBack() {
    this.router.navigate([""]);
} its working.

Comment: No I mean `this.router.back()`. Or `this.router.navigate(["../"]) perhaps.

Comment: in this.router.back() ---> property back does not exist on type Router. and  this.router.navigate(["../"]) is works as same as my goBack() function.

Comment: Inject and use this one instead in your component: `private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions` (it has a `back()`)

Comment: thank you  so much. its works as i expect. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Cool! Let me add that as the answer so it's easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html file add `(tap)="goBack()"`.

Inject this in your component's constructor: `private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions`.

In the `goBack()` function do: `this.routerExtensions.back()`.

Comment: Isnt it possible to add nsrouterlink to a button or some other layout?

Comment: Yes it is, fi. here: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-pluginshowcase/blob/c8b676734f8e9aad58e59c6379ada8964deae2cf/app/menu/menu.component.html#L8